# If echo is empty then display nothing

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a var that is either empty or not and I want to display nothing when its empty. Code Snippet:

```
<?php 
 global $bp;
 $user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id; 
 $user_info2 = get_userdata($user_id); 
?>              

<div class="meta">
 <?php _e('Status','fisa'); ?>: <?php echo fidsa_fpsa_status($user_id); ?>
</div>
```

If The var is empty it still shows Status: is there someway to change this to not output Status: when the var is empty?

Comment: You are missing context here. You should show the code (or a briefing) of _e and fidsa_fpsa_status functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `fidsa_fpsa_status($user_id)` to a variable, check if the variable is empty - if its not, print the content!

```php
<?php 
global $bp;
$user_id = $bp->displayed_user->id; 
$user_info2 = get_userdata($user_id); 
$fidsa_fpsa_status = fidsa_fpsa_status($user_id);

 if (!empty($fidsa_fpsa_status)) {
    ?> 
     <div class="meta">
         <?php _e('Status','fisa'); ?>: <?php echo $fidsa_fpsa_status; ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked 100% simple enough. Thanks for assisting with this.